# connecting to mongodb replicaSet with nestjs and typeorm is not working

Tags: mongodb, nestjs, typeorm

#### problem

I'm trying to connect to mongodb with nestjs(^8.2.3) and typeorm(^0.2.28)
In test environment, connecting to mongodb standalone server is working. For your information, node mongodb library version is ^3.6.2.

**production sample code(nestjs server)**

I referred the [typeorm code](https://github1s.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/HEAD/src/driver/mongodb/MongoDriver.ts#L488-L493) to write mongodb options

```
import { TypeOrmModule } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { MongoConnectionOptions } from 'typeorm/driver/mongodb/MongoConnectionOptions';

export const configForOrmModule = TypeOrmModule.forRootAsync({
  imports: [],
  useFactory: async () => {
    const mongodbConfig: MongoConnectionOptions = {
      type: 'mongodb',
      username,
      // for replicaSet (production)
      hostReplicaSet: 'server1.example.com:20723,server2.example.com:20723,server.example.com:20723',       
      replicaSet: 'replicaSetName'
      port: Number(port),
      password: encodeURIComponent(password),
      database,
      authSource,
      synchronize: true,
      useUnifiedTopology: true,
      entities: [Something],
    };

    return mongodbConfig;
  },
  inject: [],
});
```

But in production environment, when nestjs server try to connect to mongodb replicaSet, the server get this server selection loop error message over and over again like below. Interesting thing was the domain that the server tried to connect was different from replicaSet hosts(ex. `another-hostname` not included in `server1.example.com:20723,server2.example.com:20723,server.example.com:20723`). (**+ edited: the another hostname is actual physical server indicated by the dns(server.example.com)**)

```
 [39m01/28/2022, 2:39:16 AM [31m  ERROR[39m [38;5;3m[TypeOrmModule] [39m[31mUnable to connect to the database. Retrying (3)...[39m
MongoServerSelectionError: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND <another-hostname>
    at Timeout._onTimeout (/home/node/app/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/sdam/topology.js:430:30)
    at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:557:17)
    at processTimers (node:internal/timers:500:7)
```

#### what I’ve tried but these not worked

1. remove `useUnifiedTopology: true` option
2. downgrade `mongodb` library version to 3.5.11 (I've read in mongodb community there are something bug with topology after 3.6 version)
3. use host option not the hostReplicaSet

if you need more information, please tell me. thank you for your helping.

Answer (score 1):

It was kubernates DNS issue. The hostReplicaSet `server1.example.com:20723,...` is resolved to `host1` (physical server name. without `example.com`) but, k8s doesn't know it. so connection was failed.

there are two options

1. update kubernates /etc/hosts setting to add host1 -> host1.example.com
2. or update mongodb hostname host1 -> host1.example.com